# Echarts : Uncaught Error: Component series.force not exists. Load it first

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, echarts

I want to use the echarts to make a Data Visualization Force layout, when i follow the step to setup all option, it has an error, said

> **Uncaught Error: Component series.force not exists. Load it first**

i think it might be javascript goes wrong, so i change another version of the echarts.js, but the error still exist, and anyone help me ?

btw, this is my second post on stackoverflow, still learning how to use this platform, so if anywhere that you think i can describe the problem better, pls tell me, thanks.

here is my javascript cdn

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0-release/echarts.js"></script>
```

and here is my main code

```
<div id="main" style="width: 1280px;height:800px;"></div>
<script>
    // init
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

    // if the website is still loading, show the animation
    // myChart.showLoading(); 

    var data = data_format(jdata);

    var option = {
        title : {
            text : 'test',  // this field will connect to the book name
        }, 
        tooltip : {}, 
        toolbox : {
            show : true, 
            feature : {
                saveAsImage : {
                    title : 'save as image',
                    show : true, 
                    type : 'png'
                }
            }
        }, 
        legend : {}, 
        series : [
            {
                type : 'force', 
                name : 'test', 
                ribbonType : false, 
                categories : [
                    {
                        name : 'person'
                    }
                ], 
                itemStyle : {
                    normal : {
                        label : {
                            show : true, 
                            textStyle : {
                                color : 'black'
                            }
                        }, 
                        nodeStyle : {

                        }
                    }
                }, 
                minRadius : 15, 
                maxRadius : 25, 
                gravity : 1, 
                scaling : 1, 
                linkSymbol : 'arrow', 
                steps : 10, 
                coolDown : 1, 
                nodes : data.nodes,
                links : data.links
            }
        ]
    }

    // setup all option
    myChart.setOption(option);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series) (click on the series node on the left menu to open it and see all types) `series` has no `force` type
Valid types are: e.g. `bar`, `graph`, etc.

Maybe this [example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph-force) will help you. It uses a series of type graph which has a [force](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-graph.force) object.

e.g. from the example:

```
series : [
    {
        type: 'graph',
        layout: 'force',
        force: {
            repulsion: 100
        }
        ...
```

Comment: oh, i see

you mean there don't have the  force type, and the `force` layout is include in the graph type, so i have to change the type name.